# DateTime Parameters in MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I'm working on a program where I am sending a `DateTime` variable to a sortable jQuery DataTable.
This is the constructor in my "Model" file:

```
 public StudentDailyStatus(int studentID, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, string code, string status, int goodDays, int badDays, int leave, int lengthOfStay)
```

And then here are the values that I am trying to put into the object:

```
 new StudentDailyStatus(1, (2015, 1, 1), (2015, 2, 1), "1","Normal","2",0,0,0),
```

My error is: "[the file] does not contain a constructor that takes 4 arguments".

But I'm having issues with the `startDate` and `endDate` parameters.  How do I use the `DateTime` variables?
Thanks for your help!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using SAAS.Models;

namespace SAAS.Services
{
    public class StudentDailyStatusService
    {
        private static readonly List<StudentDailyStatus> StudentDailyStatuses;

        static StudentDailyStatusService()
        {
            StudentDailyStatuses = new List<StudentDailyStatus>
            {
                // StudentID, StartDate, EndDate, Code, Status, GoodDays, BadDays, Leave, LengthOfStay
                new StudentDailyStatus(1, new DateTime(2015, 1, 1), new DateTime(2015, 2, 1), "1","Normal",2,0,0,0),
                new StudentDailyStatus(1, new DateTime(2015, 1, 3), new DateTime(2015, 1, 4), "1","Normal",2,0,0,2),
                new StudentDailyStatus(1, new DateTime(2015, 1, 5), new DateTime(2015, 1, 6), "1","Normal",2,0,0,2),
                new StudentDailyStatus(1, new DateTime(2015, 1, 7), new DateTime(2015, 1, 8), "1","Normal",0,0,0,2),
                new StudentDailyStatus(1, new DateTime(2015, 1, 9), new DateTime(2015, 1, 10), "1","Normal",2,0,0,2),
                new StudentDailyStatus(1, new DateTime(2015, 1, 11), new DateTime(2015, 1, 13), "1","Normal",2,0,0,2),
                new StudentDailyStatus(1, new DateTime(2015, 1, 12), new DateTime(2015, 1, 14), "1","Normal",2,0,0,2),
                new StudentDailyStatus(1, new DateTime(2015, 1, 15), new DateTime(2015, 1, 16), "1","Normal",2,0,0,2),
                new StudentDailyStatus(1, new DateTime(2015, 1, 15), new DateTime(2015, 1, 16), "1","Normal",2,0,0,2),
                new StudentDailyStatus(1, new DateTime(2015, 1, 19), new DateTime(2015, 1, 20), "1","Normal",2,0,0,2),
                new StudentDailyStatus(1, new DateTime(2015, 1, 21), new DateTime(2015, 1, 22), "1","Normal",2,0,0,2),
                new StudentDailyStatus(1, new DateTime(2015, 1, 23), new DateTime(2015, 1, 24), "1","Normal",2,0,0,2),
                new StudentDailyStatus(1, new DateTime(2015, 1, 25), new DateTime(2015, 1, 26), "1","Normal",2,0,0,2),
                new StudentDailyStatus(1, new DateTime(2015, 1, 29), new DateTime(2015, 1, 31), "1","Normal",2,0,0,2),
                new StudentDailyStatus(1, new DateTime(2015, 1, 31), new DateTime(2015, 2, 1), "1","Normal",2,0,0,2),
                new StudentDailyStatus(1, new DateTime(2015, 2, 2), new DateTime(2015, 2, 3), "1","Normal",2,0,0,2),
                new StudentDailyStatus(1, new DateTime(2015, 2, 4), new DateTime(2015, 2, 5), "1","Normal",2,0,0,2),
                new StudentDailyStatus(1, new DateTime(2015, 2, 6), new DateTime(2015, 2, 7), "1","Normal",2,0,0,2),
                new StudentDailyStatus(1, new DateTime(2105, 2, 8), new DateTime(2015, 2, 9), "1","Normal",2,0,0,2),
                new StudentDailyStatus(1, new DateTime(2015, 2, 10), new DateTime(2015, 2, 11), "1","Normal",2,0,0,2),
                new StudentDailyStatus(1, new DateTime(2015, 2, 12), new DateTime(2015, 2, 13), "1","Normal",2,0,0,2),
                new StudentDailyStatus(1, new DateTime(2015, 2, 14), new DateTime(2105, 2, 15), "1","Normal",2,0,0,2),
                new StudentDailyStatus(1, new DateTime(2015, 2, 16), new DateTime(2015, 2, 17), "1","Normal",2,0,0,2),
                new StudentDailyStatus(1, new DateTime(2015, 2, 18), new DateTime(2015, 2, 19), "1","Normal",2,0,0,2),
                new StudentDailyStatus(1, new DateTime(2015, 2, 20), new DateTime(2015, 2, 21), "1","Normal",2,0,0,2),
                new StudentDailyStatus(1, new DateTime(2015, 2, 22), new DateTime(2015, 2, 23), "1","Normal",2,0,0,2),
                new StudentDailyStatus(1, new DateTime(2015, 2, 24), new DateTime(2015, 2, 25), "1","Normal",2,0,0,2),
                new StudentDailyStatus(1, new DateTime(2015, 2, 26), new DateTime(2015, 2, 27), "1","Normal",2,0,0,2),
                new StudentDailyStatus(1, new DateTime(2015, 2, 28), new DateTime(2015, 3, 1), "1","Normal",2,0,0,2),
                new StudentDailyStatus(1, new DateTime(2015, 3, 2), new DateTime(2015, 3, 3), "1","Normal",2,0,0,2),
                new StudentDailyStatus(1, new DateTime(2015, 3, 4), new DateTime(2015, 3, 5), "1","Normal",2,0,0,2),
                new StudentDailyStatus(1, new DateTime(2015, 3, 6), new DateTime(2015, 3, 7), "1","Normal",2,0,0,2),
                new StudentDailyStatus(1, new DateTime(2015, 3, 8), new DateTime(2015, 3, 9), "1","Normal",2,0,0,2),
                new StudentDailyStatus(1, new DateTime(2015, 3, 10), new DateTime(2015, 3, 11), "1","Normal",2,0,0,2),
                new StudentDailyStatus(1, new DateTime(2015, 3, 12), new DateTime(2015, 3, 13), "1","Normal",2,0,0,2),
                new StudentDailyStatus(1, new DateTime(2015, 3, 12), new DateTime(2015, 3, 15), "1","Normal",2,0,0,2),
                new StudentDailyStatus(1, new DateTime(2015, 3, 16), new DateTime(2015, 3, 17), "1","Normal",2,0,0,2),
                new StudentDailyStatus(1, new DateTime(2015, 3, 18), new DateTime(2015, 3, 19), "1","Normal",2,0,0,2),
                new StudentDailyStatus(1, new DateTime(2015, 3, 20), new DateTime(2015, 3, 21), "1","Normal",2,0,0,2),
                new StudentDailyStatus(1, new DateTime(2015, 3, 22), new DateTime(2015, 3, 23), "1","Normal",2,0,0,2),
                new StudentDailyStatus(1, new DateTime(2015, 3, 24), new DateTime(2015, 3, 25), "1","Normal",2,0,0,2),
                new StudentDailyStatus(1, new DateTime(2015, 3, 26), new DateTime(2015, 3, 27), "1","Normal",2,0,0,2),
                new StudentDailyStatus(1, new DateTime(2015, 3, 28), new DateTime(2015, 3, 29), "1","Normal",2,0,0,2),
                new StudentDailyStatus(1, new DateTime(2015, 3, 30), new DateTime(2015, 4, 2), "1","Normal",2,0,0,2)
            };
        }

        public List<StudentDailyStatus> GetStudentDailyStatuses(int start, int length)
        {
            return FilterStudentDailyStatuses().Skip(start).Take(length).ToList();
            //return StudentAllotments.ToList();
        }

        public int Count()
        {
            return FilterStudentDailyStatuses().Count();
        }

        public IQueryable<StudentDailyStatus> FilterStudentDailyStatuses()
        {
            IQueryable<StudentDailyStatus> results = StudentDailyStatuses.AsQueryable();

            return results;
        }
    }
}
```

And the file that populates the table is:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Student - Daily Status";
    ViewBag.SubTitle = "Status History";
}

@Html.Partial("_StudentNavPartial")
@Html.Partial("_StudentSearchBar")
<div class="container-fluid left">
    <h4>@ViewBag.SubTitle</h4>

    <div class="container-fluid left">
        <table id="StudentDailyStatusTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover text-nowrap">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th data-column="StudentID">Student ID</th>
                    <th data-column="StartDate" class="text-center" id="TDtooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Date Attendance Started" data-container="body">Start Date</th>
                    <th data-column="EndDate" class="text-center" id="TDtooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Date Attendance Ended" data-container="body">End Date</th>
                    <th data-column="Code" class="text-left" id="TDtooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Attendance Status Code" data-container="body">Code</th>
                    <th data-column="Status" class="text-center" id="TDtooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Attendance Status Code" data-container="body">Status</th>
                    <th data-column="GoodDays" class="text-center" id="TDtooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Payable Days for the Student" data-container="body">Good Days</th>
                    <th data-column="BadDays" class="text-left" id="TDtooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Leave Days Paid or Unpaid for the Student" data-container="body">Bad Days</th>
                    <th data-column="Leave" class="text-center" id="TDtooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Leave Days for which the Sudent is Not Paid" data-container="body">Leave<br /> Status</th>
                    <th data-column="LengthOfStay" class="text-center" id="TDtooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Days between Enrollment and Termination" data-container="body">Length of Stay</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

@section scripts
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/dataTables")

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.extend($.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
            'pagingType': 'full_numbers',
            'pageLength': 10,
            'language': {
                'paginate': {
                    'first': '&laquo;',
                    'last': '&raquo;',
                    'previous': '&lsaquo;',
                    'next': '&rsaquo;'
                },
                'info': 'Displaying _START_-_END_ of _TOTAL_',
                'infoEmpty': 'Displaying 0 to 0 of 0',
                'infoFiltered': '',
                'search': '',
                'zeroRecords': 'No matching records found'
            },
            //'dom': '<"top"f>rt<"bottom"<"pull-left"l><"pull-right"i>p<"clear">>',
            'dom': '<"top">rt<"bottom"<"pull-left"l><"pull-right"i>p<"clear">>',
            'initComplete': function (settings, json) {
                $('.dataTables_filter input[type=search]').attr('placeholder', 'Search');
            }
        });

        $(function () {

            //jQuery(oTable.fnGetNodes()).tooltip({ //tooltip plugin for jQuery!
            //    "delay": 250,
            //    "track": true
            //});

            $('#searchButton1').click(function () {
                var filtering = "";
                var number = 0;
                var filterType = "";
                if ($('#searchSsn').val() != '') {
                    filtering = $('#searchSsn').val();
                }
                else if ($('#searchStudentName').val() != '') {
                    filtering = $('#searchStudentName').val();
                    filterType = "Name";
                }
                else if ($('#searchStudentID').val() != '') {
                    filtering = $('#searchStudentID').val();
                    filterType = "StudentID";
                }
                //Search to get studentID number and count number of results and put into "number"
                if(number == 1)
                {
                    //Filter for the one studentID retrieved from the database
                }
                else if(number == 0)
                {
                    //Show the "no results found" window
                }
                else
                {
                    //Multiple results, show the dialog box that will allow the users to choose the correct student
                }
            });

            $('#StudentDailyStatusTable').dataTable({
                'ajax': {
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetData", "StudentDailyStatus")',
                    //data: function (d) {

                    //}
                },
                columns: [
                {
                    data: 'StudentID',
                    visible: false
                },
                {
                    data: 'StartDate',
                    sortable: true,
                    className: "text-center"
                },
                {
                    data: 'EndDate',
                    sortable: true,
                    className: "text-center"
                },
                {
                    data: 'Code',
                    sortable: true,
                    className: "text-center"
                },
                {
                    data: 'Status',
                    sortable: true,
                    className: "text-center"
                },
                {
                    data: 'GoodDays',
                    sortable: true,
                    className: "text-center"
                },
                {
                    data: 'BadDays',
                    sortable: true,
                    className: "text-center"
                },
                {
                    data: 'Leave',
                    sortable: true,
                    className: "text-center"
                },
                {
                    data: 'LengthOfStay',
                    sortable: true,
                    className: "text-center"
                }
                ],
                //jQueryUI: true,
                sort: true,
                ordering: true,
                order: [0, 'StartDate'],
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true
            });

            //$('#TDtooltip').tooltip({
            //    delay: 0,
            //    track: true,
            //    fade: 100
            //});
            //$('td').tooltip({
            //    delay: 0,
            //    track: true,
            //    fade: 100
            //});
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
                delay: 0,
                track: true,
                fade: 100
            });

        });
    </script>

}
```

Okay, here's the controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using SAAS.Models;
using SAAS.Services;

namespace SAAS.Controllers
{
    public class StudentDailyStatusController : Controller
    {

        // GET: StudentDailyStatus
        public ActionResult DailyStatus()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public JsonResult GetData(DTParameters dtModel, FilterViewModel filterModel)
        {
            try
            {
                List<StudentDailyStatus> data = new StudentDailyStatusService().GetStudentDailyStatuses(dtModel.Start, dtModel.Length);
                int count = new StudentDailyStatusService().Count();
                DTResult<StudentDailyStatus> result = new DTResult<StudentDailyStatus>
                {
                    draw = dtModel.Draw,
                    data = data,
                    recordsFiltered = count,
                    recordsTotal = count
                };
                return Json(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(new { error = ex.Message });
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And here's the "models" file:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace SAAS.Models
{
    public class StudentDailyStatus
    {
        public StudentDailyStatus(int studentID, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, string code, string status, int goodDays, int badDays, int leave, int lengthOfStay)
        {
            StudentID = studentID;
            StartDate = startDate;
            EndDate = endDate;
            Code = code;
            Status = status;
            GoodDays = goodDays;
            BadDays = badDays;
            Leave = leave;
            LengthOfStay = lengthOfStay;
        }

        [Key]
        public int StudentID { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public int GoodDays { get; set; }
        public int BadDays { get; set; }
        public int Leave { get; set; }
        public int LengthOfStay { get; set; }

    }

}
```

Comment: Let's see your error and let's see the code you have written.

Comment: @JustinRusso The code is:
'code'public StudentDailyStatus(int studentID, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, string code, string status, int goodDays, int badDays, int leave, int lengthOfStay)'code'

and
'code'And then here are the values that I am trying to put into the object: new StudentDailyStatus(1, (2015, 1, 1), (2015, 2, 1), "1","Normal","2",0,0,0)'code'

The error is: It does not take a constructor that takes 4 arguments.
So I think I'm entering the dates wrong somehow

Comment: Can you edit your original post and paste the code in their?

Comment: ...and don't forget to include the error you're getting.

Comment: @JustinRusso I just did

Comment: Read my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, if you're entering the dates like this, `(2015, 2, 1)` then you're wrong.

You need to pass your dates as arguments like this... `new DateTime(2015, 2, 1)`

So, this should be your constructor call...

```
new StudentDailyStatus(1, new DateTime(2015, 1, 1), new DateTime(2015, 2, 1), "1","Normal","2",0,0,0)
```

Comment: Okay, thanks!! Is there any way to do that, but make it format?  When I run the program and get the date values with jQuery to put it in the table, the StartDate and EndDate columns are populated with values that look like this: /Date(1420088400000)/.

Any thoughts on how to make it show up in a mm/dd/yyyy format?
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, when you assign the the value in your date variable to the control, you do a '.ToString'.  So just pass in a format... dateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: How would that kind of thing work in this little block:

{data: 'StartDate', sortable: true, className: "text-center"},?

I'm populating my DataTables in a stack of blocks like this, and I'm having issues figuring out formatting in this case...

Comment: Can you post the 'StudentDailyStatus' constructor method as an "Edit" to your original post?  I'd like to see everything you're doing.

Comment: Sure!  It's just a placeholder, because eventually we'll be getting data from a database, but it'll be the same idea and variable types

Comment: I just added the file that is being used to populate the table as well

Comment: Okay, you've provided the 'StudentDailyStatusService' but not the constructor for 'StudentDailyStatus'.  I need to see where the datetime vars are being assigned to the 'String' variable which is serialized into JSON, and returned.  Probably should see the 'GetData' method of your StudentDailyStatus controller.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help!  I just put up everything associated with DailyStatus.cs... Sorry, I feel like it's something really stupid and easy that I'm probably just missing... Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: Okay, I see now.  What you need to do is change the StartDate and EndDate members of the 'StudentDailyStatus' class to be string types in lieu of datetime types.  Then, marshall the datetime values you are assigning to the StartDate and EndDate members to string values.  Ie.  StartDate = startDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Answer (score 0):

You are just sending ("2015,01,...") and not a date. You have to create a dateTime object first and then sending to your constructor.

```
new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
```

For further reference check http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: FYI - Right idea, but your reference is for JS...the code in question is C#.

Answer (score 0):

`(2015, 1, 1)` is not a `DateTime` Value... use instead `new DateTime(2015, 1, 1)`